# dist-upgrade wants to remove kubuntu_desktop

Tags: apt, upgrade, kde

I've been running ubuntu (18.04) with kde (kubuntu_desktop) on my computer for years. As of recently (at some point after upgrading to bionic), whenever I try to issue an apt-get update / apt-get dist-upgrade, it will remove kubuntu_desktop along with a lot of other packages, most of the kde-related. I will post the output at the bottom.

My questions are 
i) how does apt decide, what is going to be REMOVED ? My impression was that this should mainly affect packages that have been installed as requriments of other packages and became obsolete because the requiring package has been removed. And old kernels, of course. In my case, I have EXPLICITLY installed kubuntu_desktop.
ii) how can I prevent kubuntu_desktop from being removed?

I ran the process once, saw that kde/plasma desktop was gone, re-installed it manually (apt-get install kubuntu-desktop), but this did not change anything. With the next dist-upgrade, kubuntu_desktop remains on the list of packages to be removed.

Here is the full output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cryfs fonts-hack fonts-hack-ttf libaribb24-0 libbasicusageenvironment1 libcolorcorrect5 libcrypto++6 libdvbpsi10 libebml4v5 libgps23 libgroupsock8 libkate1 libkwinglutils11
  libkwinxrenderutils11 liblivemedia62 libmatroska6v5 libmicrodns0 libopenmpt-modplug1 libplacebo4 libqalculate6 libqalculate6-data libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsidplay2
  libtaskmanager6 libusageenvironment3 libva-wayland2 libvulkan1 libxcb-xv0 plasma-integration pulseaudio-module-gconf qml-module-org-kde-kconfig qml-module-org-kde-kholidays
  qml-module-org-kde-qqc2desktopstyle qml-module-qtwebengine vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2
  vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluedevil kate kde-config-screenlocker kinfocenter kscreen kubuntu-desktop kwin kwin-addons kwin-common kwin-x11 libkf5waylandserver5 libkscreenlocker5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1
  libkwineffects11 milou plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-desktop plasma-framework plasma-nm plasma-pa plasma-vault plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace
  print-manager sddm-theme-breeze vlc vlc-plugin-video-output
The following packages have been kept back:
  libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libwayland-egl1-mesa
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 28 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 95.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

By request, here is my output of "sudo apt-cache policy apt"

```
apt:
  Installed: 1.6.3ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 1.6.3ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.3ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.6.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

And the output of "ls /usr/share/xsessions" is

```
plasma.desktop
```

Comment: What version of ubuntu? Did you upgrade from a previous version? Do you have kde ppa or other repositories enabled ? Do you have another DE installed ? Can you also post the command you ran

Comment: My humble suggestion is that if you really want to use kde, backup your personal data and do a clean install of Kubuntu. Trying to figure out "how does apt decide, what is going to be REMOVED ?" is not a simple task without knowing a lot about your system's history.

Comment: @DK, you mean that ubuntu wants to tell me I should stop using kubuntu? In fact, I REALLY want to use kde. A "clean install" is always the very very last resort.

Comment: @panther, I clarified my question. It is an upgrade to bionic from the last LTS version. There is no kde ppa involved. I never intentionally installed another DE, but I have some grome applications that came with a lot of implicit gnome packages. The command used was "apt-get dist-upgrade"

Comment: @KOH `dist-upgrade` does not upgrade releases! It installs new dependencies (see [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)). Please add output of `apt-cache policy apt` to the question.

Comment: As I said, without knowing what you've done in the past, it's very difficult to figure out why you have the current problems. Please edit your question to include N0rbert's request as well as the output of `ls /usr/share/xsessions`. Thanks!

Comment: @N0rbert, I am perfectly aware of the purpose of `dist-upgrade`. I have added the output of `apt-cache policy apt`, although I am not sure how this would help.

Comment: @KOH So we have confirmed that you are running Bionic.

Comment: @DK, the output of `ls /usr/share/xsessions` is `plasma.desktop`. As it probably should be.

Comment: I would boot to recovery mode,  run the autoremoe, and then reinstall kubuntu-desktop . If that fails you could file a bug report or do a fresh install. The problem I have is I can not determine the offending package.  Are you running kde on wayland?

Comment: @user, I am grateful for all constructive answers. I am professionally working with linux for 16+ years, with ubuntu for 10+ years. It is just that comments about 'reinstall' are not very helpful. Moreoever, I have edited all the requested additional information into the original question!

Comment: Well, I've been running Kubuntu 16.04 and then, when Kubuntu 18.04 was released I installed that side-by-side. I too have installed some GNOME applications without facing the issues you're facing. I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: What does `apt policy libwayland-egl1-mesa` show? That's one of the held back packages? I have `Installed: 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1`.

Comment: @DK, thanks for your help!! My problem might be related to wayland. I have the same installed package as you,  it also mentions `Candidate: 1:18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1+dokomix1` which is held, probably due to problems with my fglrx driver. I am not familiar with wayland, how can I best get rid of it?

Comment: From what I recall, Kubuntu devs don't encourage users to try Wayland now. So I never looked at that asoect.

Comment: The problem disappears when I remove a ppa for the proprietary fglrx drivers. This is not a good solution, because I have an application requiring these drivers. My interpretation is that some  update in the PPA wants to install wayland components, which stall due to driver incompatibility. Apparently kde is not compatible with the resulting state and thus going to be deleted.

Comment: So it was a ppa!

Comment: If you managed to find out what the problem was, would you consider posting an answer about it?